# Is it possible to build a tensor with the following properties?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

I am searching for a tensor in 4-dimensional space-time with two indices that satisfy:

\begin{eqnarray}
M_{;\mu }^{\mu \nu } &=&0, \\
M^{\mu \nu } + M^{\nu\mu}&=&0,  \nonumber \\
M_{;\varepsilon }^{\mu \nu }+M_{;\nu }^{\varepsilon \mu }+M_{;\mu }^{\nu
\varepsilon } &=&0.  \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

An obvious choice would be the electromagnetic field strength, but I am investigating if it is possible to build a tensor with such properties that only depends on geometrical properties of the space-time manifold (metric tensor, connection). For instance, the Riemann tensor satisfies two of these properties for fixed α, β:

\begin{eqnarray}
R_{;\varepsilon }^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu }+R_{;\nu }^{\alpha \beta
\varepsilon \mu }+R_{;\mu }^{\alpha \beta \nu \varepsilon } &=&0\text{ } \\
R^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu } &=&-R^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu }  \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

But I found its divergence is zero only in very special cases, such as for maximally symmetric spaces. Is there anyway to build a tensor with these properties always, or at least in not so special cases?

Comment: I see you've posted this at Physics.SE as well. Cross-posting is not seen in good light because it duplicates efforts. Wait some time (as in a few weeks) before posting in another site in the SE network.

Comment: Ok Mark, sorry for that, I´m new to SE.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146914/2451

Answer (score 2):

If you lower the indices and consider 
$$M_{\mu \nu} = g_{\gamma \mu}g_{\delta \nu}M^{\gamma \delta},$$
then $M_{\mu \nu}$ is a two form (by equation two), is co-closed (first equation) and closed (third equation). Thus you are looking for a harmonic two form. (I am treating these as Riemannian manifolds, so I hope I did not misunderstand the concepts).

Comment: Thank you very much. My knowledge on differential geometry does not goes much beyond whats strcitly  needed to understand basic general relativity. I couldn´t find some easy material about harmonic forms... do you know where I can learn it? Can the components of these harmonic two forms be funcions of the metric, or at least functions of manifold onto real numbers?